# make center align bottom page footer in asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I am facing one problem

my footer in page stays down but it not at center.

its right aligned now

I want make it to center aligned.

earlier it was not even staying down but then applied .footerContent css  which is mentioned below.

after applying .footerContent. it solved my problem of footer not being bottom of page. now its at bottom but shows extensively right . half of footer gets cut.

can u guys correct n show me whats wrong.

I am attaching here screen so that u can position of footer.
[see here](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/fdKowa6n_ds6XKw7VrLAiqgQo4Txt-5HHe9QuOgWekg=w353-h207-p-no)

**heres markup**

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header" runat="server">
        <%-- Menu goes here --%>
      </div>    
      <div id="masterpageContent" class="footer">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
      </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="footerContent">
        <div class="footerbrd">
        </div>
        <p class="clear">
        </p>
        <div class="footer">
            <div class="c1 fleft">
                Best viewed in IE8 and above with Resolution 1024x768
            </div>
            <div class="c2 fleft">
                (c) Copyright 2013 
                <br />
                All Rights Reserved.
            </div>
            <div class="c3 fright">
                Site by abc Team
            </div>
            <p class="clear">
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

**and heres css**

/*footer start*/

```
.footerbrd {width:929px; height:1px; background:#ef0b14; margin:0px auto;}
.footer {width:929px; margin:0px auto; padding:5px 0px; color:#666666;}
.footer .c1 {width:300px; margin:0px; padding:0px;}
.footer .c2 {width:375px; margin:0px; padding:0px; text-align:center;}
.footer .c3 {width:254px; margin:0px; padding:0px 0px 0px 0px; text-align:right;}
ul.foot {list-style:none; padding: 0px 0px; margin: 0px;}
ul.foot li {list-style:none; float:left; line-height:12px;}
ul.foot li a {color:#666666; padding: 2px 10px; font-size:11px; text-decoration:none; display:block; float:left;}

.footerContent { 
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 929px;
    margin: auto;
    bottom: 0px;   
}
```

/*footer end*/

Comment: the ans below should solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

Change width to `100%` in `.footerContent` and set its margin to `0 auto`. It should work for you.

Comment: no change ganesh. its the same. i have added error image in description so that u can see position of footer.

Comment: Although this question is old, but I used @TusharSale .footercontent  and what Ganesh Pandhere said, and footer now shows in the center.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question on google and found the solution to your problem (it is a bit late, but for everyone who is looking)

The page should look like this:

```
<html>
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>

        <link rel="Stylesheet" href="../Scripts/layout.css" />

    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="wrapper">
            YOUR PAGE HERE      

          <div id="push">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="footer">
        YOUR FOOTER HERE    
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And in the 'layout.css' file (save it in the 'Scripts' folder in your website), add this:

```
.wrapper 
{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -20px;  /*the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height*/
}
.push
{
    height: 20px;  /*'.push' must be the same height as 'footer'*/
}
.footer
{ 
    position: absolute;
    height: 20px;
    width: 99%;
    margin: auto;
    bottom: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
```